# RFC_READ_TABLE example convert data back to table

Tags: dynamic, abap

I am desperate with trying to read a table over RFC and get it converted back.

This is my code so far, everything works properly.

```
DATA: lt_options LIKE TABLE OF rfc_db_opt,
      lt_fields LIKE TABLE OF rfc_db_fld,
      lt_data LIKE TABLE OF tab512,
      lt_entries type table of DPR_PHA_TYPE.


CALL FUNCTION 'RFC_READ_TABLE'
  DESTINATION 'Y58CLNT800'
  EXPORTING
    query_table = 'DPR_PHA_TYPE'
  TABLES
    options     = lt_options
    fields      = lt_fields
    data        = lt_data.
```

I just don't know how to get `lt_data` converted back to a table like `lt_entries`.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the table structure of `DPR_PHA_TYPE`? This table is not present in the systems I have access to.

Comment: The solution depends on if you are working an an unicode system or not. Could you please state some more information about the SAP system you are working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be as simple as

```
  DATA: lt_options TYPE TABLE OF rfc_db_opt,
        lt_fields  TYPE TABLE OF rfc_db_fld,
        lt_entries TYPE TABLE OF dpr_pha_type.


CALL FUNCTION 'RFC_READ_TABLE'
  DESTINATION 'Y58CLNT800'
  EXPORTING
    query_table = 'DPR_PHA_TYPE'
  TABLES
    options     = lt_options
    fields      = lt_fields
    data        = lt_entries.
```

However, this will only work if the table in question contains only character fields.

Comment: Do you know any solution, if for instance `DPR_PHA_TYPE` is only in system `Y58` available but not in the current system, where we execute the function? I would appreciate it. I am aware, that I can get the fields name and offsets from `lt_fields`. I just don't know how to put them dynamically together.

Comment: Personally, I would use the `TYPES` directive to create an equivalent local data type and use that.

Comment: Aaah now I got that. Sorry I was a little bit confused.